# How do you replace a nested triple for loop that sets some values using the Java 8 streams API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I’m trying to navigate over 3 lists (nested triple for loops) and set some values based on a match. Below is a class representation and also the triple for loops I’m iterating over and doing the setting based on a match.

My question is, how would I replace the loops included below, using the streams API?

I’m new to Java and trying to wrap my head around Java 8 features. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you and have a wonderful day!

Listed below are the classes involved and the loops which I want to replace with the Java 8 streams API:

Thanks very much in advance all!  Have a great day!

**CLASSES:**

```
class B {
  Long Id;
  Long x;
  String y;
  Long z;
}

class A {
  private  Long Id;
  private  List<B> bList;
}

class C {
  private  Long Id;
  private  List<Long> bIds;
  private  String y;
  private Long z;
}
```

**NESTED FOR LOOPS:**

```
void f(List<A> aList, List<C> cList) {
    for(A a : aList) {
      List<B> bList= a.getBList();
      for(B b : bList) {
        for(C c : cList) {
          if(a.getId().equals(c.getId()) && c.getBIds().contains(b.getId())) {
            b.setZ(c.getZ());
            b.setY(c.getY());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: "How?" is but the form, following the function of "Why?". Why do you want to transform this code? --- Streams - by their nature - are stateless. It is not impossible to transform this code into a "streamified" version, but I doubt that it will be faster or more readable.

Comment: Please don't try to turn this into a `Stream` version.  What you've written is clear enough.  Writing this with streams would make it much harder to read and understand.

Comment: Sandeep, assuming that you're looking at this as an opportunity to learn about streaming concepts, my advice is to separate this into two parts. First to produce a stream of (A, B, C) triples, and second to carry out some operation on those. Second part first, if you had a stream of (A, B, C), can you figure out how to do the operation? First part second, consider conceptually the set of all (A, B, C) triples -- this is the Cartesian product of the sets of A, B, and C. Can you figure out a way to filter the Cartesian product? Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Your nested for loops are fine. It would look like a train wreck if converted to streams.

Comment: It's doable, but I suspect it would be less readable than it is now.

Comment: I would suggest, if you haven't done this already, getting practice converting FOR loops into STREAMS with a forEach, but start with something simpler. You can also convert the IF statements into filters as well.

Comment: It's tricky because of the nested nature of the data (A contains bList, c contains bIds, you would probably have to create a method for each level of the loop (so 2 - 3 methods, depending on how you did it). I'm sure it's doable, but it would be much uglier than the above nested loops. Your call, of course.

Comment: You realize that streams just hide the iterations.  The idea of streams is to make the code more descriptive and thus readable than efficient.   I would suspect the the best thing to do is try and restructure the classes/design so you don't have to have the three lists to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with the other answer about not overcomplicating or obfuscating the logic with streams; however you could technically do something like this:

```
void f(List<A> aList, List<C> cList) {

    Map<Long, C> cIdToCMap = cList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, item -> item));

    aList.stream().forEach(a -> a.getBList().stream()
            .filter(b -> cIdToCMap.get(a.getId()).getBIds().contains(b.getId())).forEach(b -> {

                C c = cIdToCMap.get(a.getId());
                b.setY(c.getY());
                b.setZ(c.getZ());
            }));
}
```

I did a little preprocessing to put the C's in a map by ID to reduce the need for extra looping. But you could have done this:

```
void f(List<A> aList, List<C> cList) {

    aList.stream().forEach(a -> a.getBList().stream().forEach(b -> {

        cList.stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(a.getId()) && c.getBIds().contains(b.getId())).forEach(c -> {

            b.setY(c.getY());
            b.setZ(c.getZ());
        });
    }));
}
```

Keep in mind this second one, which is closest to your code, does overwrite values if there are duplicate IDs found.  In both this code and your code, the last match wins.